Phone number with flags are not visible on Community pages Salesforce LWC
I want to show phone number with flags like that:

But the flags images are showing like that

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import flagTelpicker from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/flagTelpicker';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
export default class Phoneflag extends LightningElement {
    datepickerInitialized = false;
    //https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html
    renderedCallback(){
        if(this.datepickerInitialized){
            return;
        }
        this.datepickerInitialized = true;
 
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this,flagTelpicker + '/css/demo.css'),
            loadStyle(this,flagTelpicker + '/css/intlTelInput.css'),
            loadScript(this, flagTelpicker + '/js/utils.js'),
            loadScript(this, flagTelpicker + '/js/intlTelInput.js')
        ]).then(() => {
            this.initFlagpicker();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    initFlagpicker(){
        const input = this.template.querySelector("[data-id=phone]");
        window.intlTelInput(input, {
            separateDialCode: true,
            // excludeCountries: ["il"],
            preferredCountries: ["us", "in"],
            initialCountry: "US",
        });

    }
    handleFieldChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
}

I want to add the phone with flags functionality on Community page Salesforce.

I presume this is your starting point Phone number with Flag in LWC?

Also please explain more clearly what your problem is.

I have got a problem with the flags whereas they are not exactly cropped correctly and other country flags are partially shown on community page, it is working on record page.
